# Comparing two arrays using a if loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, if-statement

I am trying to compare if one array is greater then the other array using a IF statement.

```
from scipy.stats import laplace
from pylab import hist, title
from numpy import random


n = 10000

r = laplace.rvs(size=n)
normal = random.random(n)
new = r/normal

naccept = 0 

if (new > normal):
    naccept = naccept + 1 
else: 
    pass

print('Acceptance fraction: ', naccept/n)
```

I get the following error

```
  File "<ipython-input-64-b66ee75060af>", line 14, in <module>
    if (new > normal):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What am I missing because both arrays are float64 so they should compare and return the acceptance fraction.

Comment: What do you mean by one array being "greater" than another? That it has more items? That the average value is higher? That the maximum value is higher?

Comment: Do you want to compare the lengths of the arrays?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The goal is to compare each value in each array to see if the first array (new) first value is greater then the second array (normal) first value then repeating that over the array and returning an acceptance fraction of naccept/n

Comment: @Sid not the lengths but I want to compare each individual value in each array.For example new(1) > normal(1)   if this is true or false it would add to naccept then move on to new(2) > normal(2) until the end of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With numpy, a boolean operation on an array results in a boolean array.

It seems that you would like to count the number of times an element in the new array is above its counterpart in the normal array. You were almost there: simply count the number of `True` elements in the boolean array `new > normal`:

```
from scipy.stats import laplace
import numpy as np 

n = 10000

r = laplace.rvs(size=n)
normal = np.random.random(n)
new = r/normal

# this counts the number of "True" (1) in the array (`False` is 0)
naccept = np.sum(new > normal)

print('Acceptance fraction: ', naccept/n)
```

yields:

```
Acceptance fraction:  0.3754
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. Adding that np.sum got the acceptance fraction i needed. Thank you